# how to get cell id in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

**c#**

```
 for(int k = 0; k < tableAppointment.Rows[0].Cells.Count; k++)
            {
                cellID = tableAppointment.Rows[0].Cells[k];
    }
```

**aspx**

```
<table id="tableAppointment" runat="server">
        <tr Class="csstextheader">
            <td class="csstextheader" width="70px">
                                        </td>
            <td class="csstextheader" width="70px">
                                            <b>Time Slot&nbsp;</b>
                                        </td>
            <td ID="9"><span>C</span></td>

        </tr>
</table>
```

How do i get the cell Id?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile since `tableAppointment` is not a server control.

Comment: normally you can tableAppointment.Rows[0].Cells[k].ID or tableAppointment.Rows[0].Cells[k].ClientId but the table and cells do not have runat server attr so you cannot access them on server side. And to be honest this approach does not look nice if you can explain what you are trying to achieve we can find another solution. Cheers.

Comment: i miss runat server in quetion now i have update

Comment: you should also add runat=server for tr and td tags. For asp.Net the ID="9" is just a HTML attr nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 for(int k = 0; k < tableAppointment.Rows[0].Cells.Count; k++)
 {
     var currentCell = tableAppointment.Rows[0].Cells[k];
     string ID = currentCell.Attributes["ID"]; //for this, k must be count-1, the last cell
 }
```

Determining the cell with the ID, the last cell e.g. `tableAppointment.Rows[0].Cells[2] or tableAppointment.Rows[0].Cells[Count-1]`